# Numerical Range with En Dashes & Hyphens (a $3–$5-million-a-year business). Is this punctuated acceptably?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, dashes, range-inclusion

Is this acceptably punctuated? En dashes used between the numbers, and hyphens in the compound modifiers. I believe the two examples below are clear and concise. Do you agree with the punctuation (i.e., en dash and hyphens) in each exemplar?

a $3–$5-million-a-year business

a $50,000–$60,000-per-year increase in funding

Answer (score 1):

No, those two **not** acceptably punctuated — not due to the rule books, but because they don’t pass the smell test around here.  Those are way too cumbersome to attempt, no matter whether they’re right or wrong.

However, it’s obvious that if you get to elide the millions, so too the thousands.

But in any event, just because you manage to learn correct English doesn’t mean you’ll ever find anyone whom you can speak it with.

In other words, it will be awkward and stilted no matter what you do so long as you insist on conjoining so many hyphens and dashes.  It’s an ungainly punctuation-heavy approach that people would never write that way, even if they might say it that way.

So either leave out some dashes or hyphens, or better yet, rephrase so that these silly is-it-ok-to-use-symbols-and-commas-and-hyphens-and-dashes-with-my-$100–300,000-words-in-one-compound-adjective issues never arise:

- a $50–60k annual funding increase
- a small business (that is, one earning $3–5m per year)

Comment: Why isn't the $ symbol repeated before 60k and 5m? These abbreviations look like the k for kilometer(s) and the m for meter(s).

Comment: @whippoorwill Because they just aren’t, that’s why: you have five to ten dollars in your pocket, never five dollars to ten dollars. The prefix dollar symbol **$** distributes rightwards across the numbers following it just as the postfix *dollar* word distributes leftwards across numbers that precede it. It’s simply how it is said and written. As for abbreviations, that’s a shame, but it’s how it’s used.  Were they indicative of some metric prefix, there would be a space.  You may use capital M for millions if you must. Of course, in programming, these numbers are different.

Comment: So the same would apply here, too, right? ---a 70–80% increase ... a $65–70 savings ...don't repeat the % and $ symbols. These two exemplars (lol) look good?

Comment: And these? a $65–70 million increase; a $100–150,000 savings (good?)

Comment: Based on your samples, I think these'd fall in line with your way of thinking: a $6-12 million per year job
a 10-20% per year increase
a $5-10,000 a year job
a $1-2 per day charge

Comment: I found an answer in the Associated Press Q&A, which calls for suspended hyphenation: Q. Without recast: $2 million- to $5 million-a-year contract? OR $2-million- to $5-million-a-year contract? Thanks. – from Loudonville, NY on Wed, Jul 28, 2010
A. the first is correct.

Comment: Based on their guidance, my original examples would be punctuated like this: a $3 million- to $5 million-a-year business ...

a $50,000- to $60,000-per-year increase in funding

Comment: But they don't hyphenate in the following instance. What the heck?? Q. We have to use the percent symbol at my work. Without a recast, does this look OK without the hyphens? a 30% to 35% a year increase in revenues (instead of: a $30%- to 35%-a-year increase in revenues). – Thu, Feb 06, 2014
A. Using AP guidance in the "percent" entry, a 30 to 35 percent a year increase in revenues. We don't use the percent sign for technical reasons. Others do.

Comment: AP is not being consistent here. Based on their guidance it should be: a 30 to 35 percent-a-year increase in revenues

Comment: Their contradictory advice (hyphenate the modifiers in the monetary range but not the percentage range) makes no sense at all.